# Output number as character

Tags: javascript

I have created a list where a number between 1 and 5 can be selected via select. Now I would like the output to appear as a character instead of a number. So instead of (for example) 5 should be +++++ and 3 should be +++. How do I proceed?

The value is output in a template string as a number and should also be replaced there by the characters.

`<div class="importance">${todo.prio}</div>`

Comment: [String.repeat() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`String#repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat).

```js
const todo = {prio: 5};

// for example
document.body.innerHTML = `<div class="importance">${"+".repeat(todo.prio)}</div>`;
```